# What is the significance of 1.000000015047466e+30?

Tags: machine-learning, math, pytorch, floating-point, cuda

I was attempting to do JIT compilation on a pytorch-based module from an NLP library and I saw that one of the generated fused CUDA kernel code implementations mentions the number `1.000000015047466e+30`:

```
#define NAN __int_as_float(0x7fffffff)
#define POS_INFINITY __int_as_float(0x7f800000)
#define NEG_INFINITY __int_as_float(0xff800000)


template<typename T>
__device__ T maximum(T a, T b) {
  return isnan(a) ? a : (a > b ? a : b);
}

template<typename T>
__device__ T minimum(T a, T b) {
  return isnan(a) ? a : (a < b ? a : b);
}

extern "C" __global__
void fused_add_mul_mul_sub(float* tattn_mask1_1, float* tac_2, float* tbd_2, float* output_1, float* aten_mul_1) {
{
if (blockIdx.x<1ll ? 1 : 0) {
if ((long long)(threadIdx.x) + 512ll * (long long)(blockIdx.x)<169ll ? 1 : 0) {
if (blockIdx.x<1ll ? 1 : 0) {
        float v = __ldg(tattn_mask1_1 + (long long)(threadIdx.x) + 512ll * (long long)(blockIdx.x));
        aten_mul_1[(long long)(threadIdx.x) + 512ll * (long long)(blockIdx.x)] = v * 1.000000015047466e+30f;
      }    }  }if ((long long)(threadIdx.x) + 512ll * (long long)(blockIdx.x)<2028ll ? 1 : 0) {
    float v_1 = __ldg(tac_2 + (long long)(threadIdx.x) + 512ll * (long long)(blockIdx.x));
    float v_2 = __ldg(tbd_2 + 12ll * (((long long)(threadIdx.x) + 512ll * (long long)(blockIdx.x)) % 169ll) + ((long long)(threadIdx.x) + 512ll * (long long)(blockIdx.x)) / 169ll);
    float v_3 = __ldg(tattn_mask1_1 + ((long long)(threadIdx.x) + 512ll * (long long)(blockIdx.x)) % 169ll);
    output_1[(long long)(threadIdx.x) + 512ll * (long long)(blockIdx.x)] = (v_1 + v_2) * 0.125f - v_3 * 1.000000015047466e+30f;
  }}
}
```

It feels like this should be some sort of FLOAT_MAX constant, but I don't know any numerical type that would have this as a limit.

Google searching for this constant just yields a handful of results that seem to suggest it may be a physical constant of some kind:

- [This MATLAB forum link](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/496643-error-in-merge-multiple-netcdf-files-in-a-folder-to-one-file-using-lavnish-gupta-netcdf-add-on-in-m) suggests it may be a default value for some physical phenomena
- [This Github repo on whole cell electrophysiology](https://github.com/johndempster/WinWCPXE/blob/master/SETFITPA.dfm#L156) seems to use it as a max limit of some kind.
- [This Opensea NFT link](https://opensea.io/assets/matic/0x2953399124f0cbb46d2cbacd8a89cf0599974963/115745459846495047462184448337615078963565200670166152504000622232494409777153) shows that the number is somehow used as a parameter for some kind of fractal art?

I'm absolutely baffled because I'm doing natural language processing using CUDA and have absolutely no clue why this number is appearing in my CUDA kernel code and why it's also being used in hard science research code. Does this number have some special floating point properties or something? Is it serving as a numerical stability factor somehow? Any leads would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Great question. You could look at that number represented as an integer or decomposed into exponent and mantissa -- maybe there is a pattern that's obvious there. Something that's strange to me, the arguments are floats, so those are 8 significant digits, but that constant has 16 significant digits or thereabouts (I didn't count).

Comment: @ShreyGupta This value is `1.0e30f` in disguise. It has no special significance in CUDA. Is the code in the question *machine-generated* by any chance? Various software has been using `1.0e30f` as a "huge" value for `float` over the past 30 years. If the code was generated by a program, try locating the constant in the generator's source code. Can you clarify and specify the "NLP library" by name?

Comment: I wonder why they did not choose a nice round number such as `1267650600228229401496703205376.0f` (`==pow(2,100)`)

Comment: @chtz That's a trick question, correct? Most programmers hate to type verbose stuff like that :-) The use of `1.0e30f` as a "huge" `float` value can be traced back *at least* to Sun's fdlibm from 1993, and it seems that the authors of various software simply copied that value forward to the present day. In 1993, we could not yet write `0x1.0p+100f`, as hexadecimal floating-point literal constants made their entrance with C99. As OP notes, the value is significantly smaller than `FLT_MAX` on most systems. Why `1.0e30f` was chosen (versus say, `1.0e38f`) I have not been able to find out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`1.000000015047466e+30f` is 10<sup>30</sup> rounded to the nearest value representable in `float` (IEEE-754 binary32, also called “single precision”), then rounded to 16 decimal digits, then formatted as a `float` literal.

Thus, it likely originated as `1e30` or another representation of 10<sup>30</sup> that was subsequently converted to `float` and then used to produce new source code.

(The `float` nearest 10<sup>30</sup> is exactly 1000000015047466219876688855040.)